# Assigning Audio Object to Variable Equaling Function

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I am creating  sound library for my game and I'm trying to make it as clean and flexible as possible. My end goal is to be able to define a variable (as in the below code) and call it in this manner `sound1.play()` or `sound1.mute()` etc, like an audio object. How would I go about doing that? My thought was that if I passed the variable name to the function (eg, sound1) and assign it the audio object, then theoretically it would work.

```
var sound1 = new brazen({
  source:[
    ['audio/hit1.mp3'], // mp3
  ],
})
```

Although, I tried that, passing the variable name, but I was still unable to call it via `sound1.play()`.

**THIS WORKS**

```
this.newSound = new Audio(soundName); // sound1.newSound is now an audio object
this.newSound.play(); // sound1.newSound.play() plays the sound
```

**WHAT I WANT**

```
this = new Audio(soundName); // sound1 is now an audio object
this.play(); // sound1.play() plays the sound
```

How do I go about achieving my goal? Obviously the "What I Want" does not work since you cannot assign the audio bit to THIS. I want to achieve this dynamically for any variable declared as "new brazen()"

Ideally javascript only solutions as I hope to have this library be standalone, but I will accept Jquery if it's the only solution.

Comment: Why do you try to assign a value to `this`?  What does `new brazen()` return?

Comment: Lack of proper understanding of the `this` along with trying to find a solution to my problem. `new brazen` currently does not return anything... give me a minute I'll test something

Comment: What is issue with using approach which returns expected result?

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured out the solution... sorry haha :) I'll edit my question to contain the answer and mark it as answered. Thank you btw, as your comment on asking what `new brazen()` returned helped me realize my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND A SOLUTION**

I feel silly for not trying this earlier, but the below gives me my desired result. It was stupidly simple.

```
s = new Audio(soundName); // sound1 is now an audio object
return s; // Var sound1 = audio object and assumes properties of HTML audio object, including .play();
```